# Why should we care about the root test?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In an introductory calculus class, students typically learn about both the ratio and root test for determining convergence of series. 
However, the ratio test seems sufficient enough for determining the radius of convergence of any power series that the students might encounter, and series where the root test is easier to apply then the ratio test, like 
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left (\frac{n+1}{2n} \right )^n$$

are rather artificial. I am aware that we need the root test to prove that the radius of convergence for a power series is exactly $\frac{1}{\limsup{\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}}$, but other than this, what are some naturally arising examples in mathematics where the root test would be the go-to choice to test for convergence that students in a calculus class might care about?

Comment: Here is a little puzzle which is easy with root test but not so much with ratio test: prove that if $b_n$ is a sequence which converges to $b\in(-1,1)$, then $\sum_n b_n^n $ converges absolutely.

Comment: What is so artificial about $\sum\left(\frac{n+1}{2n}\right)^n$? I TA'd calc II for a year and saw plenty of more ridiculous series than that...

Comment: @Math1000, that series does not arise in any context that anyone cares about other than being a calculus exercise. Do you disagree? It's like telling someone a convergence test will be useful because it may show up on an exam. That's not what people mean when they ask how something is useful.